# Is it possible to create a docker image that just contains non executable files copied from host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

Is it possible to create an image of the contents of a folder on host. And later extract the content from image to the machine? 
If so how?

**Here is my failed attempt:**

**Dockerfile**

```
WORKDIR '/data'
COPY ./hostfolder .
```

**Command executed:**

docker build -t mydata .

```
Folder structure:
```

[image]

**Error:**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Error response from daemon: No build stage in current context
```

Comment: basically there should be an option for that. but if you share your purpose for doing so I might suggest a better solution with docker, as it would be nontrivial to create a dockerfile for this purpose

Comment: Why do you want to use Docker here – an image generally contains a complete executable file and its dependencies?  Why not, say, a tar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a docker image as a place to store and then extract files.

First, you are missing a `FROM` directive in your `Dockerfile`. This is the reason for your error:

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR '/data'
COPY . .
```

Then, to build the image:

```
$ docker build -t temp .
```

Then, to extract files, start the container:

```
$ docker run --detach --name data temp
```

and copy from the container to the host:

```
$ docker cp data:/data ./result
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I needed.